# Show Tabs menu except Login Page?

Tags: ionic3

i set Login page as root page in app.component.ts. After Login success navigate to Home page.
in this case tabs menu not showing Home page. but i need to show menu in home page only not in login page. please help me.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is too many ways to do that ,
in login page you can store login token for example , using native storage .

```
this.storage.set('token',YourLoginData);
```

in your app.component.ts constructor get the storage value :

```
this.storage.get('token').then(res=>{
                                    if(res){
                                       this.rootPage=HomePage;
                                         this.pages =[
                                           { title: 'HOME', component: HomePage },
                                            //..... ALL PAGES YOU WANT 
                                         ];
                                     }else{ this.rootPage=LoginPage}


                 });
```